# Stack push pop rotate

Tags: c, stack

This program has the functions push, pop and rotate. The rotate function is supposed the top three items on the stack

If the numbers in the stack are:

```
2
6
5
8
9
```

---

After you call the `rotate` function they should be:

```
5
2
6
8
9
```

---

The push and pop functions are correct, i'm just not sure how to implement this rotate function correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

struct node* push(struct node* top, int i) {
   struct node *new_node;
   new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   if(new_node == NULL) {
    printf("malloc failed");
        return top;
   }

   new_node->value = i;
   new_node->next = top;
   return new_node;

}

struct node *make_empty(struct node *top) {
   return NULL;
}

struct node *pop(struct node *top, int *i) {
   struct node *new_node;
   new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   if (new_node == NULL) {
    printf("malloc failed");
    return top;
   } 

   *i = top->value;
   new_node = top;
   top = top->next;
   free(new_node);
   return top;
}

struct node *rotate(struct node *top) {

   struct node *new_node;
   struct node *prev = top;
   struct node *cur = top;
   int i;

   new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   if (new_node == NULL) {
    printf("malloc failed");
    return top;
   }

  i = cur->value;
   top = top->next;

   new_node->next = top->next;
   new_node->value = cur->value;

   return new_node;
} 
void print_stack(struct node *top) {
   struct node *p;
   if(top != NULL) {
      for(p = top; p !=NULL; p=p->next)
    printf("%d\n", p->value);
      printf("\n");
   }
   else
      printf("stack is empty\n");
}
```

Comment: how about pop1,pop2,pop3, push3,push1,push2

Answer (score 1):

use the code you already have

```
int v1,v2,v3;
pop(stack, &v1);
pop(stack, &v2);
pop(stack, &v3);
push(stack, v3);
push(stack, v1);
push(stack, v2);
```